# Is this "unsafe" declaration unnecessary?

Tags: c#

I have a class that I inherited from someone else. It is doing a P/Invoke on [CopyFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to copy a file (we are using UNC shares if that matters). The code is marked `unsafe` but I thought you only needed to use that when dealing with raw pointers, if you are using `IntPtr` only your code does not need to be marked unsafe.

```
public void Copy()
{
    bool result;

    unsafe
    {
        if (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 5)
        {
            //only newer versions of windows support the no buffer flag
            //(this is set because copying large files on a computer with limited ram will pretty much kill the computer)
            result = CopyFileEx(SourceFile, TargetFile, new CopyProgressRoutine(CopyProgressEvent), IntPtr.Zero, ref Cancelflag, CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_NO_BUFFERING);
        }
        else
        {
            result = CopyFileEx(SourceFile, TargetFile, new CopyProgressRoutine(CopyProgressEvent), IntPtr.Zero, ref Cancelflag, 0);
        }
    }


    //file copy failed so get the DLL error and throw an exception
    if (result == false)
    {
        Win32Exception exc = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        throw exc;
    }
}


//xcopy file progress event handler
private CopyProgressResult CopyProgressEvent(Int64 TotalFileSize, Int64 TotalBytesTransferred, Int64 StreamSize, Int64 StreamBytesTransferred, uint dwStreamNumber,
                                                   XCopy.CopyProgressCallbackReason dwCallbackReason, IntPtr hSourceFile, IntPtr hDestinationFile, IntPtr lpData)
{
    //chunk of a file finished copying
    if (dwCallbackReason == XCopy.CopyProgressCallbackReason.CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED)
    {
        int currentFilePercent = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(TotalBytesTransferred * 100.0 / TotalFileSize));

        //only send a new message when something changes (prevents flooding of messages)
        if (currentFilePercent != LastFilePercent)
        {
            LastFilePercent = currentFilePercent;

            //Report back the progress
            ProgressCallback.Report(currentFilePercent);
        }
    }

    //stop the copy?
    if (Cancelflag == 1)
        return XCopy.CopyProgressResult.PROGRESS_CANCEL;
    else
        return XCopy.CopyProgressResult.PROGRESS_CONTINUE;

}

//win32 API call
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool CopyFileEx(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName,
    CopyProgressRoutine lpProgressRoutine, IntPtr lpData, ref Int32 pbCancel,
    CopyFileFlags dwCopyFlags);

//xcopy event handler
public delegate CopyProgressResult CopyProgressRoutine(
                    Int64 TotalFileSize,
                    Int64 TotalBytesTransferred,
                    Int64 StreamSize,
                    Int64 StreamBytesTransferred,
                    uint dwStreamNumber,
                    CopyProgressCallbackReason dwCallbackReason,
                    IntPtr hSourceFile,
                    IntPtr hDestinationFile,
                    IntPtr lpData);
```

I think the `unsafe` is not needed but the person who wrote this originally claims he was getting intermittent errors during run-time when in production environments when it was not marked unsafe.

Was he right about needing `unsafe` or did he have a problem elsewhere that was just fixed at the same time that made it look like `unsafe` fixed the issue?

Comment: Are you sure just using `System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 5` is okay?  What happens if the program is run on another OS (say Unix)?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse then I got much bigger problems when `[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]` fails. This application is for internal office use, we do not have any non windows workstations this program could be run on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`unsafe` is purely a compile-time check. If it were needed the code wouldn’t compile. The runtime errors are caused by something else.

Furthermore, `unsafe` is needed if and only if you are using unmanaged pointers (e.g. inside a `fixed` block).

Comment: Actually, there is one other situation where `unsafe` is required: when using `fixed` buffers.